# Need to convert string to JSON in LogStash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have Logstash ingesting a log, in JSON format. It has a specific field that contains JSON. Logstash is treating that specific field with JSON as a string since the value is quoted. I want Logstash to treat the contents of that field as JSON also, but can't figure out how to strip out the quotes.

Here is the log:

```
{"Time":"2014-06-16","Hostname":"FOOname","Event":"Warning","CustomField":"{"Title":"This is the data treated as a string","User":"FooUser"}"}
```

The quotes around the value of "CustomField" cause the issue.

Answer (score 8):

What is your current config and what version of Logstash are you running?

I would assume the following would work:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "CustomField"
    target => "CustomFieldParsed"
  }
}
```

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/json

If your JSON is in the Title field then

```
    source => "CustomField.Title"
```

Comment: I'm using Logstash 1.4.0.   My config looks like<br>

Comment: I'm using Log 1.4.0.   I already had the json{source=>"message"} which properly formated the main part of the log.  If my CustomField looked like "CustomField":{"foo":"bar"}, then the json would be created correctly.  But since there is a double quote around the {"foo":"bar"}, it treats {"foo":"bar"} as a string value of "CustomField".     This is a windows event that has been json formated and shipped by nxlog.  The nxlog treated the custom event "message" from the Event Log as just a string.  I was hoping to fix it in the logstash ingest.

Comment: Use the json filter a second time then perhaps to extract json from one of the fields.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.  Earlier I tried a second json filter, and got _jsonparsefailure and thought maybe you couldn't have two json filters.  But I'll give it another shot.  Thanks

Comment: Filters are executed in order, so it will act on the structure of the log after the first filter has been actioned, not the original structure.

Comment: In my case I had to make sure to use a different name for the target as done in this example. Otherwise it would just skip the log entirely.